# How to build a BLE mesh node using HM-10?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, hm-10

I'm new to BLE and have been reading on BLE mesh and it seems perfect for my application.

I have multiple [HM-10](https://components101.com/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/HM10%20Bluetooth%20Module%20Datasheet.pdf) modules and I'm able to send/receive data using a simple Arduino connection and a BLE scanner app on my Android.

However, I want to step up and build a BLE mesh network. I've looked online but I can't find any resources on how to use these HM-10 modules as mesh nodes. What is the best way to start working on this? How do I implement the BLE mesh stack on an HM-10?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't.

Bluetooth Mesh was released in [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_mesh_networking), four years *after* your module was made. It is highly unlikely that your module includes any mesh capability.

It is based on the [CC2540](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2540.pdf) chip from Texas Instruments, a pretty limited 8051-based microcontroller released in 2010, so even if you reflash your module with custom code it's probably not possible to add mesh support.